# Adding a ScrollPane is making my JTextArea disappear

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

If I have the scrollbar, the JTextArea just vanishes. Without it, everything is fine. Can someone please explain this to me? And how to fix it!

Also, as an aside, is it possible to change the color or set a border on the scrollpane?

Here is the relevant code:

```
        //Text Container
    JPanel textCon = new JPanel();
    textCon.setOpaque(false);
    textCon.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    add(textCon);

    //Left Filler
    JPanel left = new JPanel();
    left.setOpaque(false);
    textCon.add(left);

    //Text area
    mainText = new JTextArea("SAMPLE");
    mainText.setOpaque(true);
    mainText.setSize(50,30);
    mainText.setLineWrap(true);
    mainText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textCon.add(mainText);

    //Set textAre fonts, colors, border/padding
    mainText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
    mainText.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 10));
    mainText.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    mainText.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //Scroll Bar
    scroller = new JScrollPane(mainText);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    mainText.add(scroller);
```

And here is the rest of it, just in case!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.*;

class ProjectMain extends JFrame
{
//Declare String/Array for mainText
String output = "";
String [] hero;
int page = 0;
JTextArea mainText;
JScrollPane scroller;

public ProjectMain()
{
    //Set Background
    setTitle("JLA Viewer");
    setSize(1920,1080);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bg.png")));
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    //Refresh Background
    setSize(1919,1079);
    setSize(1920,1080);

    //Label Container
    JPanel labelCon = new JPanel();
    labelCon.setOpaque(false);
    labelCon.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(labelCon);

    //Top Label
    JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("JLA Profile Viewer");
    topLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    topLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    topLabel.setOpaque(false);
    topLabel.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 30));
    labelCon.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,topLabel);

    //Logo
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel();
    logoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    logoLabel.setIcon(logo);
    labelCon.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,logoLabel);

    //Text Container
    JPanel textCon = new JPanel();
    textCon.setOpaque(false);
    textCon.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    add(textCon);

    //Left Filler
    JPanel left = new JPanel();
    left.setOpaque(false);
    textCon.add(left);

    //Text area
    mainText = new JTextArea("SAMPLE");
    mainText.setOpaque(true);
    mainText.setSize(50,30);
    mainText.setLineWrap(true);
    mainText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textCon.add(mainText);

    //Set textAre fonts, colors, border/padding
    mainText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
    mainText.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 10));
    mainText.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    mainText.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //Scroll Bar
    scroller = new JScrollPane(mainText);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    mainText.add(scroller);

    //Right Filler
    JPanel right = new JPanel();
    right.setOpaque(false);
    textCon.add(right);

    //Button Container
    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    buttonContainer.setOpaque(false);
    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,buttonContainer);

    //PREV Button
    JButton prev = new JButton("PREV");
    prev.setOpaque(false);
    ActionListener PrevList = new PrevButton(); //Call Button Listener
    prev.addActionListener(PrevList);
    buttonContainer.add(prev);

    //EXIT Button
    JButton exit = new JButton("EXIT");
    exit.setOpaque(false);
    ActionListener ExitList = new ExitButton(); //Call Button Listener
    exit.addActionListener(ExitList);
    buttonContainer.add(exit);

    //NEXT Button
    JButton next = new JButton("NEXT");
    next.setOpaque(false);
    ActionListener NextList = new NextButton(); //Call Button Listener
    next.addActionListener(NextList);
    buttonContainer.add(next);

    //File Handling
    try
    {
        File inputFile = new File ("ProjectInputFile.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            output = output + (scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {

    }

    //Add split strings to array
    hero = output.split("@");
}

//Prev button event listener
public class PrevButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        page = page - 1;
        if(page < 0)
        {
            page = hero.length;
        }
        mainText.setText(hero[page]);
    }
}

//Exit button event listener
public class ExitButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

//Next button event listener
public class NextButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        page++;
        if(page > (hero.length))
        {
            page = 0;
        }
        mainText.setText(hero[page]);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new ProjectMain();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This line

mainText.add(scroller);

attempts to add a `JScrollPane` to a `JTextArea`. You have already set the `ViewPortView` of the `JScrollPane` so this line is unnecessary.

You will still need to *add* the `JSrolllPane`:

```
textCon.add(scroller);
```

Also make sure to call `JFrame#setVisible` *after* all components have been added.

```
setVisible(true);
```

> is it possible to change the color or set a border on the scrollpane?

Sure. Instead of setting the border on the `JTextArea` `mainText`, set it on the `JScrollPane`.

*Side notes:*

- Don't silently catch `IOException` without showing the exception content
- `JFrames` are typically used directly rather than extending

Comment: Thanks but that didn't really help. Without adding the scroll pane, I have no scroll pane. Adding the scroll pane makes the JTextArea disappear. I extended the JFrame because it is for a project in college and that is the way the lecturer wants it for some reason.

Comment: Add the `JScrollPane` to the `textCon` `JPanel` rather than to the `JTextArea. See update

Comment: Again, I appreciate you taking the time to help, but if I add the scroll pane to the textCon then the layout gets messed up. I assumed this was because it is on a grid and all three slots are taken, so I got rid of one of the filler panels and added the scroll pane in it's stead but then I just get a big grey block taking up that space of the grid, whether I set opaque to false or not and still no scroll pane. This is only a college project and I have a work around (less text = no need to scroll ;D) so it's not that important, it is just annoying me that I can't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to `setBounds(x,y,z,w)` to your `JScrollPane` and not your `JTextArea`. Then add your `JSrcollPane` to your `JFrame` of your `JPanel`.